# Show that $2(\sin y + 1)(\cos y + 1) = (\sin y + \cos y + 1)^2$

Tags: trigonometry

The question states:

> Show that: $$2(\sin y + 1)(\cos y + 1) = (\sin y + \cos y + 1)^2$$

This is what I have done

$2(\sin y + 1)(\cos y + 1) = 2(\sin y + \cos y + 1)^2$

L. H. S.                = R. H. S.

From L. H. S.

$2(\sin y +1)(\cos y + 1) = 2(\sin y\cos y + \sin y + \cos y + 1)$

$= 2(\sin y\cos y + \sin y + \cos y + \sin^2 y + \cos^2 y)  (\sin^2 y + \cos^2 y = 1)$

$= 2(\sin^2 y + \sin y\cos y + \sin y + \cos^2 y + \cos y)$

I got stuck here. I do not know what to do from here.

I have tried and tried several days even contacted friends but all to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin y=s,\cos y=c$$

$$(c+s+1)^2=c^2+s^2+1+2c+2s+2cs=2\underbrace{(1+c)}+2s\underbrace{(1+c)}=?$$

Another way

As $s^2+c^2=1$

$$(s+(c+1))^2=s^2+(c+1)^2+2s(c+1)=1-c^2+(c+1)^2+2s(c+1)=(c+1)[1-c+c+1+2s]=?$$

Comment: I have also proved from R.H.S. to L.H. S., but I thought it can also be shown that it can be established that L.H.S.= R.H.S.

Comment: @Favour, it hardly matters, right? In some derivations like $$\tan(A+B)=\tan(\pi-C)$$ the RHS, LHS come together after simplification. Definitely you can multiply out the LHS, and replace $1$ with $$\sin^2+\cos^2$$ to reach RHS, but that'll be artificial in the sense that that is not how the problem came into being.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the RHS,

$$\color{blue}{(\sin y + \cos y + 1 )^2} = \sin^2 y + \cos^2 y +  1 +2\cos y \sin y + 2\cos y + 2\sin y$$
$$= 1+ 1 +2\cos y \sin y + 2\cos y + 2\sin y=2(1+\cos y \sin y + \cos y + \sin y) = 2 \left[(1+\cos y) + (\sin y + \cos y \sin y ) \right] = 2 \left[(1+\cos y) + \sin y(1 + \cos y) \right]=\color{blue}{2(1+\cos y)(1+\sin y )}$$

Comment: I have also proved from R.H.S. to L.H. S., but I thought it can also be shown that it can be established that L.H.S.= R.H.S.

Answer (score 1):

If you have difficulty finding clever groupings, you could brute-force the problem by expanding everything and seeing what happens:

Writing $c := \cos y$ and $s := \sin y$ to save typing, we have

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
2(s+1)(c+1) &= (s+c+1)^2 \\
2(s c + s + c + 1) &= s^2 + c^2 + 1 + 2 s c + 2 s + 2 c \\
\cancel{2s c} + \cancel{2s} + \cancel{2c} + 2 &= s^2 + c^2 + 1 + \cancel{2 s c} + \cancel{2 s} + \cancel{2 c} \\
2-1 &= s^2 + c^2 \\
1 &= \sin^2 y + \cos^2 y \quad\checkmark
\end{align}$$
Since the steps are reversible, the identity is verified. $\square$

Comment: I have also proved from R.H.S. to L.H. S., but I thought it can also be shown that it can be established that L.H.S.= R.H.S.

Comment: If you can go from one side to the other, and if your steps are reversible (eg, you aren't introducing sign issues from squares or square roots), then you *can* start at the other side. Sometimes, doing so is silly. For instance, if you had $\sin^2x+\cos^2x-1=0$, then it's *obvious* how to simplify the left-hand side to get $0$. To start with the right-hand side, you'd need to expand $0$ to $1-1$, and then rewrite the first $1$ as $\sin^2x+\cos^2 x$. This works, of course, but it's a bit like pulling rabbits from a hat. You look clever, but the reader's understanding isn't well-served.

Answer (score 0):

$$RHS - LHS=(\sin y + \cos y + 1)^2-2(\sin y + 1)(\cos y + 1) $$

$$=[(\sin y +1)+( \cos y + 1) -1]^2-2(\sin y + 1)(\cos y + 1) $$

$$=(\sin y +1)^2+( \cos y + 1)^2 + 1 -2(\sin y + 1)-2(\cos y + 1) $$
$$=[(\sin y +1)^2-2(\sin y + 1)+1]+[( \cos y + 1)^2 - 2(\cos y + 1)+1] -1 $$
$$=\sin^2 y+\cos^2 y -1  = 0$$